# upgrade to scala 2.13 breaks some simple SortedMap remove entry code

Tags: scala

I was running the following code on Scala 2.12 fine:

```
  private[this] var requestByTimeoutById: SortedMap[Long, Map[String, Request]] = SortedMap.empty

  def drop(request: Request): Unit = {
    requestById = requestById - request.command.msgUuid
    // more logic
  }
```

After upgrading to Scala 2.13.7 I get a compile error:

```
[error] /Users/Shared/trex/core/src/main/scala/com/github/trex_paxos/Driver.scala:90:31: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scala.collection.Map[String,BaseDriver.this.Request]
[error]  required: scala.collection.SortedMap[String,BaseDriver.this.Request]
[error]     requestById = requestById - request.command.msgUuid
```

Asking IntellJ to open the definition of the function I get to:

```
  @deprecated("Use - or removed on an immutable Map", "2.13.0")
  def - (key: K): Map[K, V]
```

Which is clearly returning the wrong type. How do I remove an element in the `scala.collection.SortedMap`?

Comment: Import `SortedMap` from the immutable package and the code will still work as expected.

Comment: Are you sure that `requestById` is a `SortedMap`?  If it's statically known that it is, there's a chance you're hitting an IntelliJ bug where it's choosing the definition in `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I can do this:

```
requestById = requestById.filterNot(key => key.equals(request.command.msgUuid))
```

which seems really clunky. Is there a more idiomatic way?

Comment: Instead of referencing an immutable collection with a `var` identifier, it usually make more sense to reference a mutable collection with a `val` identifier. Then you can remove an element in a `mutable.SortedMap` by using the `-=` method.